# Hibernate envers add audit column (username)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Requirement is to add username column for every audit entry.

After googling a lot and going through the enverse docs I figured out how to implement it. I have implemented it as follows:

Implemented a revision listener:

```
@Configurable
public class UserRevisionListener implements RevisionListener
{
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity)
    {
        UserRevEntity revision = (UserRevEntity) revisionEntity;
        String username = "";
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();

        if (principal != null && principal instanceof DepotUser)
            username = ((DepotUser) principal).getUsername();

        revision.setUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Create an entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_REV_ENTITY")
@RevisionEntity(UserRevisionListener.class)
public class UserRevEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    private String              username;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I have referred a link that has an example of the same "[Thinking in Software](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/03/auditing-entities-with-hibernate-jpa.html) ".

Default auditing is working fine.

Firstly, the table for the audit revision with the new username column should get auto generated (**I think!**). Its not getting generated.

So, I tried by creating the table and adding the table mapping in **UserRevEntity**. But no luck.

Can anyone help my identifying the issue?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class DefaultRevisionEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@RevisionNumber
private int id;

@RevisionTimestamp
private long timestamp;

// ... rest of the class body here....
```

This is DefaultRevisionEntity, which has already declared with id & timestamp.
For your new column username, it has to be annotated as @Column in UserRevEntity as given below.

```
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
```